# how to get url value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the crated the page and in the submit i call the another page. I pass the id and name in the url

my url is like

http://localhost/sfrefer/sf-refer-ap.php?id=45&cust_name=testing

in sf-refer-ap.php

i use the following code

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
$mobile= $_POST['mobile'];
$custname1= $_POST['cust_name'];
echo $custname1;
$sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (name,email,mobile) VALUES ('$cust_name','$email[$i]', '$mobile[$i]')";
```

empty value is going into database....
How to insert the id and cust_name in db

Comment: you send GET parameters not POST. use $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: use $_GET[''] in palce of post

Comment: Learn about [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) before fixing this

Comment: Debug you code. It would have told you that there is nothing in `$_POST` because you are using querystrings. Also wide open to both XSS and sql injection attacks.

Comment: if your  submitting form data use post method it's safe and secure..

Comment: @jhon that's a silly remark. Just changing the verb doesn't make it magically safe nor secure.

Comment: @jhon No it's not?! POST is still plain text, its just *slightly* harder to view

Comment: @PeeHaa, In console nothing happen.... in my php output is Notice: Undefined index: cust_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\sfrefer\validate.php on line 12

Comment: @Peehaa How can i store the url value in hidden type...<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="<?php echo $_POST['cust_name']?>" /> and i used in another file $name=$_Post['name1']; but it does not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `GET` when passing data in URL, use `POST` only on submit. try to change your code into:

update: You should initialize your variable first and then use isset to make sure that the data was passed with the correct value.

```
$id= ""; 

$custname1= ""; 

if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['cust_name'])){ 
$id= $_GET['id'];
$custname1= $_GET['cust_name'];
 echo $custname1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `GET` method to pass `id` and `cust_name`. Because you passed values on url `id=45&cust_name=testing`

```
$id =  $_GET['id']; 
$name= $_GET['cust_name'];
```

You should be checking whether the index `cust_name` actually exists in the `$_GET` array before attempting to use it.

```
if(isset($_GET['cust_name'])){ $name = $_GET['cust_name']; }
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: cust_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\sfrefer\sf-refer-ap.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are little bit confused. use the following

```
$name= $_GET['name'];
$mobile= $_GET['mobile'];
$cust_name= $_GET['cust_name'];
echo $cust_name; // cust name echoed here
```

if you want to save cust_name in your database table use name columns value as $cust_name

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (name,email,mobile) VALUES ('$cust_name','$email[$i]', '$mobile[$i]')";
```

if you want to save name in your database table use name columns value as $name

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (name,email,mobile) VALUES ('$name','$email[$i]', '$mobile[$i]')";
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: cust_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\sfrefer\validate.php on line 13
cust_name

Comment: can you post your complete code

Comment: my mistake only

Comment: is it working fine now ?

Comment: yes.can i store the value in hidden field

Answer (score 0):

```
(isset($_POST['name']))? $name= $_POST['name'] : $name = "";
(isset($_POST['mobile']))? $mobile= $_POST['mobile'] : $mobile="";
(isset($_POST['cust_name']))? $custname1= $_POST['cust_name'] : $custname1 = ""; 
echo $custname1;
```

But if you want the id from your url change one of the variable to

```
(isset($_POST['id']))? $id= $_POST['id'] : $id = "";
```

If you do 
`echo $id` you will have the id

To avoid at the minimum sql injection use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (name,email,mobile) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $cust_name)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email[$i])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mobile[$i])."')";
```

`$con` is your connexion for mysql maybe your variable name is different.